# meaning of "null" NextShardIterator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The DynamoDB Streams GetRecords API reference says about NextShardIterator:

```
"If set to null, the shard has been closed...";
"Length constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 2048."
```

What does null means in this context then?
Does this mean that this parameter is omitted in the GetRecords result?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> What does null means in this context then? Does this mean that this parameter is omitted in the GetRecords result?

That's right. It'll be omitted from the result.

For Kinesis Streams(underlying implementation is same), if no more records are available for closed shards, `GetRecords` API returns

`{
    "Records": [],
    "MillisBehindLatest": 34000
}`

Comment: Five years after this question was asked, the DynamoDB still doesn't explain what a "null" NextShardIterator means, and Google searches yield conflicting information. However, I tested, and **this** is the correct answer. Indeed, if you read with `GetRecords` until the end of a closed shard, `NextShardIterator` will be missing in the response - not "null" in any other sense. I tested this by disabling streaming, which the documentation explains will close all the open shards - and indeed does.